# Ssh + ldap not asking for private/public key

Tags: linux, ldap, centos6, pam

I have fully configured a LDAP server which works perfectly for authenticating users across my multiple nodes.

I wanted to add an extra layer of security with the usual two factor public private key.

I followed this guide : https://github.com/jirutka/ssh-ldap-pubkey

I added the schema, i can see that my users contains a public key as their parameters.

I am able to run the script and it returns me the users public keys.

The problem is that whenever i attempt an ssh connections to my machine, it just never ask for a private key. I was wondering if there is something i am missing ?

As the guide says, i have added to my sshd.conf  :

```
AuthorizedKeysCommand /usr/bin/ssh-ldap-pubkey-wrapper
AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody
```

Rebooted, restarted but still my server never prompts for a private key. I am still able to log-in with just a user/password while it should deny me because i dind't provide a private key.

I am running on a test centos 6 machine, anybody knows if i am missing something in my PAM file ?

Comment: Did you disable password auth and enabled key auth in your sshd config?

Comment: I did not.. what exactly do you have to change. Also, I would like to keep the password auth, so that every user have to log in with Username + password + privatekey

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/17931/possible-to-use-both-private-key-and-password-authentication-for-ssh-login).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this line in sshd.conf

```
RequiredAuthentications2 publickey,password
```

Fixed the issue on CentOS 6.
Thanks to @gf_ for helping me out on this !